# Admob ads won't display because of missing permissions

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I am using Unity3d 4.5.5f1 and I followed this tutorial in order to add Admob ads into my android game.

http://youtu.be/kBRb9ba71qI

I then build my app and install it into my android phone and it says "Missing internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml." even though I have the permissions in there.

http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/0f46/vnhxlb6fia231uyfg.jpg?size_id=4

I have the AndroidManifest.xml inside Assets/Plugins and this is how it looks like.

http://www.mediafire.com/view/vfvwcmyrngie0cu/androidmanifest.txt

I just can not seem to figure this out, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: clean and rebuild your project

Comment: what do you mean by clean?

Answer (score 0):

Like LearnCocos2D said, you should try to clean your project. In Android Studio you can choose "Build > Clean Project", in Eclipse it should be something similar. I would have posted this as a comment, but I don't have the rep ;)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the problem was that I was putting the AndroidManifest.xml inside Assets/Plugins when it should be in Assets/Plugins/Android. I feel so dumb for wasting hours and hours trying to figure out such a simple mistake.